# Are there any dedicated chips for measuring logic supply voltages?

Tags: voltage, sensor

If I reboot into my PC's BIOS/UEFI I can get "instantaneous" readouts of its 12/5/3V3 voltages to 3 decimal places.

How is this classically done? Is this just a classic resistor divider into an ADC on a chip like the PCH, or is there a dedicated power-bus-checker IC? I'm working on a design and I can't seem to find anything that does this as an all-in-one chip.

Comment: 'instantaneous readouts' - Doesn't that contravene the Heisenburg uncertainty principle? Joking aside there are lots of voltmeter type chips out there. e.g. CA3162E (http://www.eleccircuit.com/the-cheap-digital-voltmeter-using-ca3162-and-ca3161/)

Comment: "a classic resistor divider into an ADC" of whatever chip would indeed be the way to go. What do you mean by "I can't seem to find anything that does this as an all-in-one chip"? There are many MCUs that include ADCs. That's a single chip, and you can do many other things with them, in addition to monitoring voltages. Why wouldn't this be appropriate for your design? What is this design you're talking about by the way?

Comment: What looks "instantaneous" to you is a long time for a normal circuit. Even if the delay was 10 ms it would look "instantaneous to you" and 10 ms is more than enough time to do some AD conversions for even a basic converter.

Comment: When I refer to all in one, I mean a chip where I can hook up the buses directly and get some sort of status output that I can connect to the mcu, whether by GPIO or I2C etc. As-is, I have to use dividers to scale the voltage (and FETs to disconnect them so I don't waste battery). It's a bunch of discrete circuitry I'd like to avoid if I can.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, for your scenario, there will always be an ADC involved, yes. The analog value must get converted to a digital DN, and then from there passed to the host OS. The most common is analog voltage -> simple filter -> SAR ADC -> SMBus/I2C -> chipset/system management controller -> some kernel (or ACPI) driver -> host OS.

ADC topologies vary wildly, but a cheap and effective type is the [SAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_approximation_ADC) ADC, commonly found integrated into many MCUs. There's also sigma-delta and a few other types that are more geared towards specific applications and performance criteria. I imagine most converters used in your average SMBus/PMBus monitor-IC will probably 10 to 12 bits, with an internal voltage reference.

In terms of external components, it varies on the type of IC. The one I've linked below from LTC is built on a semiconductor process that can tolerate direct attachment of "high" voltages (>5.5V). I think at a bare minimum, you should have a RC filter on the input to act as an anti-aliasing filter for the ADC. That said, if you are sensing "high" voltages, you may want to consider isolation -- the LTC part I've linked below additionally has a variant supporting a split SDA output for exactly this reason, as it's not safe to have an IC that can sense/see voltages up to 80V galvanically/directly connected to the rest of your system.

Once you digitize it, it's a question about how to kick it further upstairs. For most PCs, it will be an SMBus-based approach. For the purposes of this answer, you can think of I2C and SMBus together -- simple, low-cost, two-wire busses that are open-drain in nature, ignoring the protocol differences. Modern chipsets (PCH for Intel) will have a SMBus controller that software can use to talk to monitoring chips / ICs to pull data over SMBus, or respond to alerts (i.e., a SMBus voltage monitor may trigger an alert in an under- or over-voltage condition).

Shopping-wise, you're basically looking for a SMBus or PMBus voltage/current monitor IC. For example, the [LTC4151](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC4151) would give you both current and voltage data for some load. [Here is NXP's portfolio](http://www.nxp.com/products/interface-and-connectivity/interface-and-system-management/isup2-supc-bus-portfolio/isup2-supc-temperature-voltage-monitors:MC_31128?cof=0&am=0&tab=Products) of such devices as well. Google 'SMBus/PMBus/I2C voltage monitor/ic' and you should see them show up -- TI, Maxim, Linear, NXP -- all the major guys are in this market.

Answer (score 0):

Look into devices called "power management IC's."  There is a broad range of devices dedicated to providing "good/bad" on outputs based on input voltages being within a certain range.  These devices and possibly some resistors can be used to reset processors or shut down power supplies in under-voltage or over-voltage conditions.

Comment: Power management ICs are typically used to control the reset state of the uProcessor.  The question calls for a _reading_ of the voltage.